# creating "text selection" functionality (as seen in touchscreen browsers) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to create following functionality in javascript:

1. User should be able to get into **text selection mode** (by long pressing a word or clicking a dedicated button, how user goes into *text selection mode* is not important)
2. Once in *text selection mode*, two **handles** should appear on the **start** and **end** of selection which will allow user to extend the selection (users will be able to drag the handle images to extend the selection)
3. Selected text would appear in *highlighted* mode

Following is an example of the same functionality in Android 3.0 browser:
[image]

I need to create the same functionality using Javascript. I tried to searhc "javascript text select" but could not finad anything useful. **Can someone suggest me how to do this or point me to any existing work?** Thanks much.

Comment: Desktop web browsers already have a text select functionality built into them, and the way it works is exactly what the user expects. I suggest you just keep it that way.

Comment: Actually we need to add text selection functionality on a mobile site

Comment: If the site is for a mobile device, won't the mobile device do the selecting for you? On iPhone you have to specifically disable selecting (using javascript) if you don't want the user to select text. Can't you just make sure you don't disable it?

Comment: Why do you need to recreate this in JavaScript?

Comment: One example: select text and add a note?

Comment: Oh - so do you want to "fake" the native text-selection and add your own options menu when it has been selected?

Comment: I still don't see why you need to fake the selection.

Comment: Can't you let them select the text, have a long press event fire off and handle things from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are stating is a very broad user interface problem and you cannot solve it with few lines of Javascript code.  I am pretty well aware of existing mobile Javascript libraries and I have not yet come across a productized solution, because the problem in fact is really difficult.

- You need to have zoom/follow finger feature which applies complex heurestics to where the cursor actually should go
- Moving markers alongside in arbitary HTML text is troublesome - you need to have a way to split HTML to smaller pieces

Thus, I suggest you either

- Write a cross-platform faux text selection library (this is not a programming question, but a daily job for a person who knows HTML5 and mobile very, very, well)
- Post this a freelancher bounty job <-- a suggestion

From a technical point you

- can disable native text selection of devices (-webkit- special CSS styles)
- probably cannot interact with native clipboard through Javascript on mobile
- older Android devices lack proper Javascript events for the complex touch interaction in the first place

Comment: Also if you accepted a project where you are going to write a HTML5 eBook reader with this functionality you are basically screwed up